How to parse AST of C/C++ program having OpenACC pragma directives using clang and its Python bindings?
I want to parse the AST of a C/C++ program that has OpenACC pragma directives (see example below).
My eventual goal is to generate a JSON file having all the pairs of pragma-block of code the pragma operates on of a given program. So, for example, a possible JSON entry pair, with reference to the example below, could look like:
Code Example (from OpenACC GitHub) :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double *init(size_t size)
{
    double *array = (double *)malloc(size * sizeof(double));
#pragma acc enter data create(array[0 : size])
    return array;
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t size = 1000000;
    double *array = init(size);

#pragma acc parallel loop present(array[0 : size])
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = (double)i;
    }

    printf("Value before printing: %f\n", array[42]);

#pragma acc exit data delete (array[0 : size])
    printf("This should be 42: %f\n", array[42]);
    free(array);
}

For parallelizing a code block:
pragma: #pragma acc parallel loop present(array[0 : size])
code block: 
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = (double)i;
    }

OR
For data management between the (host) CPU and the (accelerator) GPU:
pragma: #pragma acc exit data delete (array[0 : size])
code block: 
printf("This should be 42: %f\n", array[42]);
    free(array);

I understand that clang, especially with its Python bindings, can allow me to parse the AST of C/C++ program using a Python script, which I would prefer using over writing a C/C++ program to do the same task. For reference, here is the Python script I have written so far:
import clang.cindex

# Initialize the clang.cindex
clang.cindex.Config.set_library_file('/usr/local/lib/libclang.so') #'/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang.so')
  
def find_openacc_directives(node):
    """Recursively search the AST for OpenACC compute directives."""
    if node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.OPEN_ACC_COMPUTE_DIRECTIVE:
        print(f"Found OpenACC compute directive at {node.location}")

    # Recurse for children of this node
    for c in node.get_children():
        find_openacc_directives(c)

def parse_file(filename):
    """Parse the file with clang and search for OpenACC compute directives."""
    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
    tu = index.parse(filename)
    find_openacc_directives(tu.cursor)

# Replace 'your_file.cpp' with your actual file name
parse_file('test2_openacc.cpp')

I want this script to print out the AST it parses so I can see what the AST looks like, and then eventually make the script generate and store a JSON file containing pairs like in the above examples. At the moment, this script I have does not print anything.
What would be a script that will work for the intents I mentioned above ? Where can I find more information or references to learn more about how to do this ?

After doing some research, unfortunately I can only offer a partial
answer.
Clang support for OpenACC is work in progress
The current (as of 2024-06-12) support in Clang is incomplete.  It is
being actively worked on, but will probably take a long time to fully
arrive.

On the OpenACC Tools page, it lists
GCC but not Clang as compilers that support it.

The Clacc
project appears aimed at adding it, but it's not clear if that effort
is still ongoing.

Based on recent-ish pull requests such as
PR #81188, commits
are landing in the Clang repo but it still seems preliminary.


If your libclang.so understands OPEN_ACC_COMPUTE_DIRECTIVE, it must
be very recent (mine, using Clang 18.1.4, doesn't).  But based on the
PRs, I don't think AST nodes are being made yet; there is just
groundwork being laid, constants defined, etc.
Otherwise, and when full support lands, I think the code in your script
should work (it does for other kinds of AST nodes).
You can't add pragmas using the Python API
Given lack of built-in OpenACC support, one might try adding parsing
support for the needed #pragmas, but that requires the C++ API.  See
How to customise pragma in C?
(which is about Clang, despite the question title) if you want to try
that route.
You could parse the pragmas yourself
One possible approach would be to do your own text-based parsing of the
#pragmas, and then correlate their locations with source locations
found in the Clang AST.  That is what I would do if I needed to parse
OpenACC right now.
You could try using a GCC plugin
Evidently GCC supports OpenACC, and it has a
plugin interface that might work.
I don't have any experience with it though.
